# sass mixin pass argument as css variable

Tags: css, sass

I have a mixin to generate some grid classes as follows:

```
@mixin grid-columns($columns) {
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .grid-col-#{$i} {
      grid-column: span #{$i};
    }
  }
}
```

I also declared a css variable at :root { --grid-columns: 12; }

i tried passing the --grid-columns variable to mixin as a variable as such

```
@include grid-columns(var(--grid-columns));
```

However, this is not working and i get the following error:

> Error: var(--grid-columns) is not an integer.
>           on line 26:23 of assets/scss/_base.scss, in mixin `grid-columns`
>           from line 26:10 of assets/scss/_base.scss
>           from line 3:9 of /stdin
>
> > @include grid-columns(var(--grid-columns));

Can anyone explain why this is not working please? I couldn't find anything online where it specifies if css variables are/are not allowed to be passed in as arguments to sass mixins, but i suspect they are not allowed?

Comment: what can we do to fix this if we wanna pass a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

SCSS does not have access to the passed CSS variable's value. You are passing only the reference to the CSS variable that is evaluated once you open the page in browser.

Therefore by doing this:

```
@include grid-columns(var(--grid-columns));
```

You are not passing the value **12** but only a reference to the **--grid-columns** CSS variable.

In the mixin

```
@for $i from 1 through $columns
```

SCSS is then confused because after **through**, there should be an integer, but it got CSS variable reference, that it does not understand and fails.